# Unable to build entity manager factory

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados, hibernate, jpa

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="default">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/blackmarket" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

O console com o erro é o seguinte

> ```
>  javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:81)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
>     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
>     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
>     at br.com.blackmarket.util.JPAUtil.criaEntityManager(JPAUtil.java:11)
>     at br.com.blackmarker.observers.InitialDataObserver.insert(InitialDataObserver.java:24)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:93)
>     at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:266)
>     at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:253)
>     at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:232)
>     at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:169)
>     at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:165)
>     at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:119)
>     at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:112)
>     at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:83)
>     at br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.init(VRaptor.java:92)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:285)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:266)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4581)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5223)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
> Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:245)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:200)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:156)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:95)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:73)
>     ... 52 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:230)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:242)
>     ... 70 more
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro foi a falta de uma depencia junto com as do maven.

mysql
    mysql-connector-java
    6.0.6